# How do I deploy ejb jar in TomEE

Tags: ejb-3.0, openejb

M exploring openejb 4 beta with TomEE, could anyone explain how I deploy ejb jar on TomEE? I'm using it for testing purposes. Also, is it possible to configure tomee in eclipse and debug through ejbs??
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are several scenarios for using EJB through the TOMEE(included OpenEJB), if you have an EAR file (consists of JARs and WAR) for deployment you need first active the APP folder in installed(means copied) TOMEE folder then you just drop your EAR file into APP folder and TOMEE unpack it and will be deployed properly.